# B tree из массива. Неужели сложность алгоритма квадратичная ?

Tags: алгоритм, дерево, сложность

В B-tree (именно B-tree а не bst) сложность добавление элемента есть `t*log(t, n)`. То есть получается если в массиве n элементов, то нам надо проделать `n*t*log(t, n)` шагов конструирования B-tree. Это есть квадратичная сложность или все-таки  `n*log(t, n)` ?

Comment: Откуда может взяться квадратичная сложность, если вставка одного элемента имеет логарифмическую сложность? Очевидно, что вставка n элементов имеет линейнологарифмическую сложность.

Comment: n*t*log(t, n) это логарифмическая сложность ? То есть так получается потому что t для данного алгоритма константа ?

Answer (score 1):

Откуда Вы взяли t?! Сложность добавления элемента в худшем случае - O(log n). Или <= c * log n, где c - некая константа. Если вставлять n элементов, то будет O(n * log n) или <= c2 * n * log n